# Use calibration weights to correct for unit non-response bias?

Tags: survey, survey-sampling, survey-weights

**I have a question about how calibration weights can be used to sufficiently correct for unit non-response bias. Suppose the sample is *s* and the response set is *r*.**

**Calibration** is applied to the response set *r* to generate weights that are as close as possible to the original sampling weights *and* meanwhile can reproduce the population totals for the selected auxiliary variables. If the auxiliary variables are (strongly) correlated with unit response probability *and* the study variables, it will help correct for unit non-response bias and reduce variance. However, I find it is not intuitive to understand this.

**Another more intuitive approach**: first, estimate the response probability using a logistic regression model, and update the sampling weights by being divided by estimated response probability, which correct for unit non-response bias; second, use calibration to further adjust the updated weights to match known population totals for certain variables, to reduce variance.

**Overall, it seems that the calibration approach (the first method) simplifies the process quite a lot, which makes me wonder it might not be the ideal approach when dealing with unit non-response.**

Any thoughts or comments would be greatly appreciated! :)